# mod_rewrite in .htaccess leads double path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove `.php` & `.html` from my website.I have a subfolder inside main directory like this

```
mywebsite.com/usa/
```

Inside usa folder i have .htaccess where i have this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It results of "mywebsite.com/usa/test.php",it give me below result

```
http://mywebsite.com/home1/user/public_html/usa/usa/test
```

Note: I do not want to disturb including functions file in test.php

Comment: Try `RewriteBase /usa/` after `RewriteEngine on` and replace `$1` to `/$1.php`

Comment: I tried but not working....yes still the same result

Comment: Not working? Still the same result?

Comment: Yes it give me the same result..can you give me simple code which remove extension from url with out harming

Comment: Try removing the both condition `RewriteCond ..` lines

Comment: if this rule is triggered, it would be visible php-extension. See other causes.

Comment: It looks like you have some other rule that is trying to redirect